# Unable to launch java file from CMD using Fully Qualified Name

Tags: java, command-line

As per title, I am able to compile the class just fine but I am unable to run it (despite using fully qualified name)

```
Boss@DESKTOP-F8O3V2Q /cygdrive/c/eclipse/workspace/MVN/3cx-driver/src
$ java com.software._3cx.main.PBXConnection
Error: Could not find or load main class com.software._3cx.main.PBXConnection
```

PBXConnection.java

```
package com.software._3cx.main;

public class PBXConnection extends Proxy {

public PBXConnection(ServerSettings settings) {
    super(settings);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
....
```

Would this be because of the package name containing `_`underscore?

Tree output

```
C:\eclipse\workspace\MVN\3cx-driver\src>tree
Folder PATH listing for volume OS
Volume serial number is 00000074 D019:C44D
C:.
└───com
    └───software
        └───_3cx
            └───main
```

DIR:

```
C:\eclipse\workspace\MVN\3cx-driver\src\com\software\_3cx\main>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is D019-C44D

 Directory of C:\eclipse\workspace\MVN\3cx-driver\src\com\software\_3cx\main

06/04/2017  16:31    <DIR>          .
06/04/2017  16:31    <DIR>          ..
06/04/2017  16:22               115 EventProcessor.java
06/04/2017  16:31             1,434 PBXConnection.class
06/04/2017  16:21             1,994 PBXConnection.java
               3 File(s)          3,543 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  355,750,649,856 bytes free
```

Edit:

```
Boss@DESKTOP-F8O3V2Q /cygdrive/c/eclipse/workspace/MVN/3cx-driver/src
$ javac -cp C:/Apache/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/lib/orderlycalls.jar com/software/_3cx/main/PBXConnection.java

Boss@DESKTOP-F8O3V2Q /cygdrive/c/eclipse/workspace/MVN/3cx-driver/src
$ java -cp C:/Apache/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/lib/orderlycalls.jar com.software._3cx.main.PBXConnection
Error: Could not find or load main class com.software._3cx.main.PBXConnection
```

Edit: Its actually Java 7 i am using (i though java 8 was running) but its not

```
Boss@DESKTOP-F8O3V2Q ~
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Boss@DESKTOP-F8O3V2Q ~
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_79

Boss@DESKTOP-F8O3V2Q ~
$ which java
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java

Boss@DESKTOP-F8O3V2Q ~
$ which javac
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javac
```

Comment: what is your CLASSPATH. And where is your class file located?

Comment: What about running `java -cp ../bin com.software._3cx.main.PBXConnection`.  (I'm guessing your class files are in a bin directory parallel to your src directory.

Comment: @SteveSmith i tried that but still no success. I even compiled .class file into the same dir as .java but still the same issue

Comment: So if you run `java com.software._3cx.main.PBXConnection` in the same directory where the filestructure `com/software/_3cx/main/PBXConnection.class` exists, you get that error?

Comment: @SteveSmith yup - and just to confirm the file actually there, its not like it has not compiled

Comment: Could you try `java com.software._3cx.main.PBXConnection $*` (dollar-star at the end).

Comment: @SteveSmith same issue `Error: Could not find or load main class com.software._3cx.main.PBXConnection`

Comment: You could try removing the underscore and see if that makes a difference?  I doubt it though.

Comment: @SteveSmith nope... even that did not help

Comment: just wondering... why is there only a `PBXConnection.class` in there? I assume: running `javac` on it did produce that `class`-file, right?

Comment: @Roland yes javac produced the class and it worked perfectly fine, its only when i try to run the class it fails. And i tried everything i know - all other projects work just fine its just this one that fails

Comment: which java version and OS are you using?

Comment: @Roland Win 10, java 8, running through cygwin

Comment: ok... I think I could reproduce it... Could you please tell how you set your classpath? During compilation and during your run.

Comment: @Roland updated question.

Comment: really strange that the `javac` didn't already produce an error... usually you use the colons on unix-like machines, but as you are probably using a windows installed java, you need to use the windows like classpath notation (which is delimited by `;`).

Comment: can you show the result of `type java` and `type javac`? (or instead of `type`: `which` or `where`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually on Linux-like systems you would set up your classpath as follows with a colon:

```
java -cp "somelibrary.jar:." MyMainClass
                         ^
```

If you however use a Windows java you will get the error you desribed, indicating that `java` is not able to find the class you specified.

If you ensure that you have a semicolon in your classpath, it should run your main class just fine:

```
java -cp "somelibrary.jar;." MyMainClass
                         ^
```

Note that if you use a unix-flavored java, the opposite is the case. You then may need to use `:` instead of `;`.

Note also: while `javac` doesn't require the `.` to find the file you want to compile (as you gave it as parameter), `java` doesn't know where to find your `PBXConnection.class`-file. You told `java` that the classpath to search for contains only that `orderlycalls.jar`. You need to explicitly say where `java` can also find your actual main-class. So the `.` is necessary when you want to run your program, but it isn't necessary in your specific case for the compiler.

Comment: Nope, still the same issue. This is just crazy all other programs compile and run just fine - ints only this project...

Comment: Yes, update showing java, Its Jv7 that is actually being used by environment - This just does not make any sense to me what so ever

Comment: but still... you are missing the `.` in your run-classpath. Updated the answer to reflect, why you need it and why it wasn't necessary for your `javac`.

Comment: hmmm, Ok i see, It compiles now fine after adding the dot...jezus that took a while. But what makes me wonder, why i do not have to do that for other programs. Just to test this out i went into other application and just run simple javac and simple java with arguments and it worked (without even specifying classpath/ nor dot)

Comment: I can only guess.. Maybe in the other cases the main class is contained in the jar-file itself? Then you do not need to add the current folder. Or the classes are dynamically loaded?

Comment: Well it is rather weird tbh.. but nevertheless :) thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It will work:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\eclipse\workspace\MVN\3cx-driver\src
java com.software._3cx.main.PBXConnection
```

Comment: well, unfortunately it does not work :( the same error

Answer (score 0):

Execute javac as below,  this would compile the class file and place it in a directory structure as per the package structure.

`javac -d PBXConnection.java`

Then execute it using the below command,

`java -cp . com.software._3cx.main.PBXConnection`

This sets the current directory as your class path and then java will be able to find the class file as per the directory structure created in the previous step.